Improve differential equation to model room temperature given input energy and outside temperature
I am trying to develop a model that will model my dorm room temperature given outside temperature and supplied energy of two electric heaters. Eventually I want to automate my room heating.
I have recorded the following data over the past couple of weeks:

Indoor temperature
Outside temperature
Socket power of my two electric heaters

(Data has been post-processed for the same time steps)
My current approach using Newton's law of cooling:
$\frac{dT}{dt} = k_1(T_{out} - T_{room}) + k_2Q $
Where I optimize for $k_1$ and $k_2$ in MATLAB to reduce the MSE between the recorded and predicted temperature using ODE23.
Here is the result I am currently getting:

As you can see the modeled temperature does not climb fast enough. I understand I should not expect a perfect prediction given all the unknowns in the system, however I am wondering if there is anything I can include in my differential equation.

do the heaters have fans? The heating looks very rapid. maybe there is convection from the fan

A different approach, but to me this looks like a classical time series regression problem

@user619894 they do not have fans however the room is very small

Are those electric heaters the only source of heat in the room?

@Vasili Yes they are

Honestly I'm surprised you get a fit that good with such a simple model. I suspect that the largest differences come from the placement of the thermometer relative to the heaters and the largest points of heat loss in the room (windows etc.), in addition to convection

I am thinking along the same lines as @whpowell96. The model presented is basically a point in space and that point is where the thermometer is placed. Ideally, $T$ is $T(x,y,z,t)$ and the modeling PDE would be a combination of cooling and diffusion from the heat sources.

@Vasili I understand what you guys are saying, however shouldn't it be possible to include a "convection term" (or two) to represent the convection from heaters and windows for which constants could also be optimized. A room volume model is not required if all I care about it a single point.

a delay term proportional to the time derivative of $Q$ might model convection/response time effects.
